# Can one use "radical" to reference the base of a word in english?

Tags: meaning, grammar, word-choice

In Portuguese and in some other languages, the use of the word *radical* indicates the base form of a word that can be derived in many other forms, but always keeping this radical, for instance: *organize*, *organizes*, and *organizing*

The *radical* (in Portuguese if you will) for those words would be **organiz**, or something similar to that. What would be the ideal term for that in the English language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, people would refer to this as the *root word*. As you can see, *radical* is even listed as a synonym here.

> **root word**
>   n (linguistics)
>   the form of a word after all affixes are removed
>   Synonyms:
>   base, radical, root, stem, theme
>   Type of:
>   descriptor, form, signifier, word form
>   the phonological or orthographic sound or appearance of a word that can be used to describe or identify something
>
> <sup>https://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/root%20word</sup>

Comment: Perfect, I'll use root as it's more usual, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Coming from the same Latin root, the word is *root*.